# Differentiating between "tends toward lambda" and "passing to the limit, converges to lambda..."

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am reading a proof in a book that uses confusing language.

To be specific, the sequence of interest is

$$Ax_n = \lambda_n x_n$$

What confuses me is that the author says "$\lambda_n$ tends toward $\lambda$" and then shortly after he says "passing to the limit we see that $\lambda$ satisfies ..."

But doesn't the first statement "tends toward $\lambda$" already imply convergence to $\lambda$, in the limit?

Why do we now "pass to the limit"?

Or are these two statements actually different?

Comment: The latter sounds like it is referring to a property preserved under taking limits. The prior is simply evaluating the limit.

Comment: Right @mrob - I agree with your comment.  Thanks,

Comment: I suspect it's because your question was so general that it seemed too ambiguous. Apparently I understood what you were asking, though, so you did a good job in my view.

Comment: You shouldn't be flagging as "unclear", @TheGreatDuck, You can vote to close on that basis, but I suggest you lighten up here.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck It's plenty clear for those who know enough to answer.  It's pretty clear here at mse that you shouldn't vote to close a question unless you can answer it.  Many questions will be unclear to users who  haven't any experience in a certain topic.  So I think the OP is clear, and you are the one who's unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the difference is, given $\{x_n\}$ converges too, that the latter means $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

The prior is just that $\lambda_n\to \lambda. $